# Android sdk setup

Tags: android, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i set up IntelliJ IDEA for android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications)

I just install IntelliJ IDEA community 12.

For the first time, when I create a Android, I create a new project SDK.

After I selected the project SDK folder, I get a no Java SDK found.

Where can I have all the project SDK setup? I browse through the configuration, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Your best shot would be with eclipse

Comment: The problem is there is no way to select the Java SDK.

Comment: Check http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96256 for the workaround.