# highlights android syntax after import android gradle based project to intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I decided to switch build system for Android project to Gradle 1.4. I use Intellij Idea IDE. After imported existing project [tictactoe](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-samples-0.3.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) based on biuld.gradle file, I can build it but Intellij Idea doesn't highlight any Android syntax, for example: Activity.

I will be very happy if someone tell me how to fix it.

Comment: [Configure Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5271182/104891) for the project.

Comment: Thank you for link, i have checked, i have correctly configured Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem was clean inteliij idea cache - File > Invalidate caches...