# cannot resolve android symbol - android app - intelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am using intellij-idea to develop android app. I created a project with an android module, but none of these :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
```

are recognized, I get `cannot resolve android symbol`. I googled this issue but none of the remarks I found there seems to debugg my problem

Comment: Right click on the module -> Open module settings -> Check the module has Android SDK dependency.

Comment: You need to setup IntelliJ for Android as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications#answer-5271194)

Comment: @rciovati sorry but where can I right click on module ?

Comment: @BackSlash in fact I set the android target again when creating a new project, and it worked !

Answer (score 7):

What you should do is,

```
1.  Select your android project
2.  press ctrl +alt + shift + S
3.  Select SDK from the project settings
4.  Check the files under the class path tab
5.  There must be android.jar ,res ,annotations.jar
Probably there should be missed one or several files in step 5.
Then,
6.  Go to Android SDK home path field and add your SDK folder again
files  even though  you have all the jars and still  you are getting the error ,then remove all the jars from the class path and add them again ( like in step 6).
7.  Build menu -Rebuild  your  project.
```

Now your errors should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

i have the answer guys
1- press ctrl+alt+shift+s
2-in the Modules bar click on your project name 
3-change the compile sdk version to the newest one 
4-click apply and ok then sync your project 
5-done , i hope the best for you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is because you didn't add Android SDK.
So you need to add android SDK.

- go to Files and select project structure.
- go to project and select the project SDK
- click New and select Android SDK version