# First time at IntelliJ - Hello Word errors

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I just made a Hello Word application Android. But, I got this errors:

```
Error(3, 19) package android.app does not exist

Error(4, 18) package android.os does not exist

Error(6, 33) cannot find symbol
symbol: class Activity

Error(11, 26)cannot find symbol
symbol: class Bundle

Error(12, 9)cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable super

Error(13, 9)cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setContentView(int)

Error(10, 5)method does not override or implement a method from a supertype.
```

When I double click error, im get this:

```
package com.example.Hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: add the android library

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645442/android-class-not-found-from-imported-jar-file

Comment: Did you install android SDK?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
[I can fixed it from this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262823/cannot-resolve-android-symbol-android-app-intellij?newreg=d77af2db727042cdb45b22c33c6e41bf) some time intelliJ has missing path/file when adding SDKs

> 1. Select your android project
> 2. press ctrl +alt + shift + S
> 3. Select SDK from the project settings
> 4. Check the files under the class path tab
> 5. There must be android.jar ,res ,annotations.jar
>      Probably there should be missed one or several files in step 5.
>      Then,
> 6. Go to Android SDK home path field and add your SDK folder again
>      files  even though  you have all the jars and still  you are getting the error ,then remove all the jars from the class path and add them again ( like in step 6).
> 7. Build menu -Rebuild  your  project.

Comment: In addition to this answer: also make sure that under project settings > modules > Android SDK points to the right SDK :), this setting can get messed up when using version control.