# Cannot resolve symbol in onCreate method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 13.1 on Windows. And one day I found my code in errors. Something like this:

[image]

It says "Cannot resolve symbol"

My Project Structure:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: what is the line number?.

Comment: @TheLostMind is it realy important?

Comment: yes.. Can't resolve which symbol??.. Show us the entire StackTrace..

Comment: did you added the import for Bundle?

Comment: @TheLostMind "Cannot reslove symbol" it is for Bundle

Comment: @MarcoAcierno yes, it is also red

Comment: i don't see it in your screen.

Comment: "And one day I found my code in errors". So was your code not having build errors before? Do a clean built. It should fix the issue

Comment: @Dinal Sorry, I'm beginer in android. Can you explain, what means "clean built". Before everything was ok

Comment: Have you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262823/cannot-resolve-android-symbol-android-app-intellij)

Comment: @Jens yes. I also did what the answer sais. But it didn't help

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to add:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```

Your IDE ought to be doing this for you. I've not used IntelliJ for a while, but I suspect you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to fix the issue ([source](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/optimizing-imports.html)).

Comment: Bundle is red and it sais "Cannot reslove symbol Bundle"

Comment: @SergaRUS Much as I appreciate you repeating your question, did you try what I just said in my answer?

Comment: @SergaRUS Try rebuilding the project: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/rebuilding-project.html

Comment: Now it sais Error:Android Source Generator: [MyApp] Android SDK is not specified

Comment: @SergaRUS Sounds like you have a lot of configuration issues, not something I can sensibly help your with through a comment discussion. I suggest finding an Android+IntelliJ tutorial and following it.

Comment: @DuncanJones I'm facing exactly the same issue as OP but when I build the project then it builds successfully and I'm even able to launch the app in emulator. How come it is possible that the IDE shows methods and classes in red but then builds successfully? Am I missing something?