# Android Dex: Unable to execute DX (IntelliJ)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dx

I follow the steps from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271194/1973953 this link.

But when i run an application i am getting these errors

[image]

i have only one line in my project.properties file "**target=android-11**"

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

So my question is why i am getting these errors and how to solve them...

Comment: From my point of view I would assume that you found a bug in the Dexifyer dx.jar (part of Android SDK).

Comment: Do you have any idea about how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Create a bug tracker entry in the [android project](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) so that Google can fix this bug in the next version.

Comment: Have you checked that you installed the compatible version of built tools?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When I had this problem it was because the ActionBarSherlock library I added to my project defined the android-support-v4.jar as a compile dependency and this jar was already included in my project so there were multiple copies/version of DEX at compile time.

The solution was to change the ActionBarSherlock module dependency for this jar to be Runtime instead of compile, as my project was already providing it.

Comment: Or just remove one of two jars which repeats

Comment: Setting it to `Runtime` doesn't work for me as my apps code also use android-support-v4.jar, so I set it to `Provided` and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I just changed the **android SDK version** in project settings (**Intellij**) and the error was resolved. I was using `API-14` but according to SDK manager only `API-19` was installed on my system. so I recommend have a look at SDK manager and see what API versions do you have and choose the right API/android version.

Answer (score 2):

You cant build using an API that is not installed on your computer.

Go to your project/module settings and select an API version that you have actually installed. Or install the API version you want in your SDK. (I would just comment on @hkazemi's downvoted answer to ask why it was downvoted, because that was the fix for me. but im so rep poor, im adding an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you added the same JAR file more than once.
If yes, remove any one of them from the `libs` folder and clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

in intellij idea:
go to project structure and delete one of the repeated .jar libraries
[worked for me]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I had added a jar to my project lib. I deleted it and 
problem solved.
You can check your project, undo your last changes to find the problem.