# how to setup intellij idea for android development

Tags: android, intellij-idea

How to setup the latest release of **Intellij idea** for android development ? I found some similar question [here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications) but it was asked in 2011 and some updates were made to android sdk and Intellij

Comment: there is [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) it is an Intellij edition for Android

Comment: I would suggest that you leave a comment in the other question (or the accepted answer for the other question) asking for an updated answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up IntelliJ IDEA for Android applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications)

Answer (score 2):

Just use Android Studio; it has everything you need right out of the box.