# I dont see the option for Android type under create new project in intelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I Installed Android SDK and JDK.

In SDK Manager I installed the packages  (Android 5.1.1 API(22), Everything under 'tools' and every thing under'extras').

I open IntelliJ , Click on 'Create New Project' Here i dont see any option for Android...

Screenshot:

http://screencast.com/t/z2yv2HkCi

Also if i go to some project's structure It never show me the option for adding Android SDK..

http://screencast.com/t/z2yv2HkCi   (no option to add android SDK)

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate.

Comment: It is just a `Gradle` based project.

Comment: If i try a Gradle project , I dont have the option to add Android SDK. How will i create an android project ... [screenshot] http://screencast.com/t/LlLQN0Wi  ...I am following this Tutorial..https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Create+a+new+Android+project

Answer (score 4):

Try to enable 'Android Support' plugin by going to Settings->Plugins->Enable Android Support

Answer (score 0):

1. Do one of the following:

   - If you are going to create a new project: click Create New Project on
     the Welcome screen or select **File** | **New** | **Project**.
     As a result, the **New Project wizard** opens.
   - If you are going to add a module to an existing project: open the project you want to add a module to, and select **File** | **New**
     | **Module**.
     As a result, the **New Module wizard** opens.

Also check this out :

2. On the first page of the wizard, in the left-hand pane, select
   **Android**. In the right-hand part of the page, select **Gradle: Android
       Module**. Click **Next**.
3. Specify your **Android module settings**, and click **Next**.
4. Specify the settings for your **Android-Gradle Foreground**
   configuration, and click **Next**.
5. Select an **Android application template** from the list, and click
   **Next**.
6. Specify the **settings** for the selected Android Activity template, and
   click **Next**.
7. Specify the name and location settings.

   Click **Finish**.

Also check this out :
[How do I set up IntelliJ IDEA for Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications)

Comment: as i mentioned in my question , I dont see the option for Android under 'create new project'...http://screencast.com/t/z2yv2HkCi

Comment: check this out  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications)