# Android SDK missing in Intellij Idea Community After installation

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am not able to resolve the error of **Android SDK** missing in **Intellij-idea** i tried as instructions mentioned in the image also i searched it on google and also tried some methods of stack overflow but it's still not resolved so please if anyone know then suggest the solution for it...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaNSt.png)

Answer (score 0):

This post ([How do I set up IntelliJ IDEA for Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications)) helped me, but had to download Android Studio and install the tools through the wizard when first launching the program.

Then I started IntelliJ and created a new project (not Android) and went to File>Project Structure and added a new Android SDK under SDKs. You have to choose the path to the SDK int the finder. To do this make sure Library is visible (see here: http://www.macworld.com/article/2057221/how-to-view-the-library-folder-in-mavericks.html) and go to Libraries>Android and choose to open SDK. After that I no longer had the problem of not finding the SDK when creating a New Android Project.